# Opencart 3 - View Cart and Checkout Section Next to Search Missing

Tags: opencart

My **View Cart** and **Checkout** section next to the search bar at the header is missing.

The other day, I changed the code in:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.twig
```

At first, I took away the `{{ cart }}` in line 77, but after that, I put it back, but still the section is missing.

I attached the image:

[image]

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: <header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div id="logo">{% if logo %}<a href="{{ home }}"><img src="{{ logo }}" title="{{ name }}" alt="{{ name }}" class="img-responsive" /></a>{% else %}
          <h1><a href="{{ home }}">{{ name }}</a></h1>
          {% endif %}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">{{ search }}</div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">{{ cart }}</div>
      
      <!--<div class="col-sm-3"></div>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</header>